# how to save/load toolstripmenuitem items/collection to properties.default.settings? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

how i can to save/load toolstripmenuitem items/collection to properties.default.settings in c#?
Or serialize to xml? What type of list I have to use?
than you, Andrius

Comment: what exactly do you want to save? item name? type? position? everything?

Comment: Item name and item text. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create simple serializable class with Name and Text properties, fill list and serialize/deserialize list like so:

```
private XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MySaveItems>));
private void SerializeToFile()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(5 * 1024))
    {
        List<MySaveItems> mySaveItemses = new List<MySaveItems>();
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStrip1.Items)
        {
            MySaveItems mySaveItem = new MySaveItems();
            mySaveItem.name = item.Name;
            mySaveItem.text = item.Text;
            mySaveItemses.Add(mySaveItem);
        }
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, mySaveItemses);
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\ToolStripItems.xml", ms.ToArray());
    }
}

private void DeserializeFromFile()
{
    using (StreamReader ms = new StreamReader("c:\\ToolStripItems.xml"))
    {
        List<MySaveItems> mySaveItemses;
        mySaveItemses = (List<MySaveItems>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MySaveItems
{
    public MySaveItems()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Reniuz,Thank you very much. And how I can load item list back to toolStrip1.Items?